# JavaScript 99 Bottles of Beer Function Not Printing to Div Correctly

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I was able to get the "99 bottles of beer..." to print correctly to the console, but as soon as I try to assign it to an element (`<p>`), only the last line prints out. Is there a simple way to insert the results continually into a div?

```
function go() {

    var beer = 99;
    while (beer > 0) {
        var verse = [
            beer + " bottles of beer on the wall,",
            beer + " bottles of beer!",
            "Take one down, pass it around", (beer - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall!"
        ].join("\n");

        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = verse;

        beer--;
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, append to the `innerHTML` instead of overwriting it each time:

```
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += verse;
```

You will probably want to replace your `\n` with a `<br />` as well, since `\n` just becomes part of a TextNode in the DOM and all whitespace is treated the same.

```
function go() {

    var beer = 99;
    while (beer > 0) {
        var verse = [
            beer + " bottles of beer on the wall,",
            beer + " bottles of beer!",
            "Take one down, pass it around", (beer - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall!"
        ].join("<br />");

        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += verse;

        beer--;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are always replacing the html of the element, try appending it like this:

```
function go() {

    var beer = 99,
        el = document.getElementById("show");
    while (beer > 0) {
        var verse = [
            beer + " bottles of beer on the wall,",
            beer + " bottles of beer!",
            "Take one down, pass it around", (beer - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall!"
        ].join("\n");

        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + verse;

        beer--;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
x = document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = verse;
```

with

```
x = document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = document.getElementById("show").innerHTML + verse;
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Charles.